# Two versions of Eulers theorem and how they relate.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am familiar with the following Euler Theorem: (Note: In the following ø(n) is the Euler function)

version i)

If gcd(x,n)=1, then $x^{ø(n)} = 1$ (mod n).

Version ii) However, I have seen the following version described as Eulers theorem too:

if $a = b$ (mod ø(n)), then $x^a = x^b$ (mod n) if gcd(x,n)=1.

My question is then, if they are equivalent, how can i show that version i) implies version ii) ? Thanks,

Comment: $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$ is a special case of [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), and $(ii)\Rightarrow(i)$ follows by specializing $\,a=\phi(n),\ b = 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a \equiv b \pmod{\phi(n)} $
means $$ a = b +k \phi(n) $$ for some integer $k$. Therefore
$$x^a = x^b  (x^{\phi(n)})^k. $$

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate why $=+()$ need to be true?

Comment: That is because the difference $a-b$ is known to be a multiple of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By $i)$, you can reduce the exponent $\bmod\varphi(n)$.  Thus we get $ii)$.